# How to use PHPUnit assert methods in a Codeception functional test?

Tags: phpunit, codeception

I'm using Codeception for unit, functional, and acceptance tests of my Laravel 4 PHP application.

My unit tests look this:

```
use Codeception\Util\Stub;
class ExampleTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test 
{
 public function testExample()
 {
  $example = true;
  $this->assertSame($example, true);
 }
}
```

My functional tests look like this:

```
use \TestGuy;
class ExampleCest
{
 public function example(TestGuy $I)
 { 
  $I->amOnPage('/auth/login');
  $I->see('Sign in');
 }
}
```

But I also want to use PHPUnit assert methods in my functional tests. But when I try to, I get this error:

**Call to undefined method ExampleCest::assertSame()**

How do I use PHP assert methods in a Codeception functional test?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertSame()`

Answer (score 34):

Since **Codeception 2.1** (not 2.0) you can use it like the other asserts with:

```
$I->assertSame($expected, $actual, $message);
```

But don't forget to enable the `Asserts` module in your config - e.g.:

```
class_name: UnitTester
modules:
    enabled: [ Asserts ]
```

**Please note:** You might need to change your configuration when upgrading to 2.1 - see upgrade instructions: http://codeception.com/06-19-2015/codeception-2.1-rc.html

Comment: This is the best answer here for the question of "how to use the Assert methods in Functional tests".

Comment: In order to see additional methods in your IDE, you have to run test suite once after config change. From codeception docs: "By default, Codeception automatically rebuilds the Actions trait on each change of the suite configuration."

Answer (score 5):

In Codeception 4 just add the Asserts Module:

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Codeception\Module\Asserts
```

to your suite.yml config file and run `codeception build`

Comment: and don't forget  "composer require --dev codeception/module-asserts"

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround can be to use Helper Methods in test suite.

For example for `assertSame()` method

```
class ExpectedHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    protected $test;

    function _before(\Codeception\TestCase $test) {
        $this->test = $test;
    }

    function assertSame($expected, $actual, $message = '')
    {
        $this->test->assertSame($exception, $actual, $message);
    }
}
```

where ***ExpectedHelper*** being the test suite Helper name (eg: **UnitHelper**, **FunctionalHelper**) which should be under ***_support*** folder

and you can use it in your test as `$I->assertSame('12340','12340');`

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same problem and somehow figured it out. Here I am going to share what I did to achieve my goal.
Step 1: Install Codeception [assert module](https://codeception.com/docs/modules/Asserts) OR simply add the following module to composer.json file and then update composer.

```
"codeception/module-asserts": "^3.0",
```

Step 2: Then it requires to enable the assert module by adding the following module in the *.suite.yml file.

```
modules:
    enabled:
        - \Codeception\Module\Asserts:
```

And finally build Codeception once again by `codecept build` OR `codeception build` whichever alias works for you.